Regex match a string that is either seperated entirely by commas or seperated entirely by semicolons
What I'm trying to do is match a string of numbers that has a "consistent" separator between its contents. For example, I want is something that matches the following:
[1,2,3,20,4] &
[5;67;8;1;6]
but NOT this list
[1,2;4;5,6,7;8]
Is there any way of implementing this feature in regex?
What I have currently is
/\[(?> \d*[,;]) * \d* \]/gx 
and while this matches the first two examples, it still matches the nonexample I gave.

what about ["foo, bar","foo","bar"]

@DanielA.White What about it? They said "a string of numbers".

You should use a capture group to capture first occurrence of ; or , and use the back-reference to make sure same delimiter is used until we match ] like this:
\[(?:\d+(?:([,;])\d+(?:\1\d+)*)?)?]

RegEx Demo
RegEx Explanation:

\[: Match opening [
(?:: Start non-capture group 1

\d+: Match 0+ digits
(?:: Start non-capture group 2

([;,]): Match ; or , and capture in group #1
\d+: Match 1+ digits
(?:\1\d+)*: Match \1 which is back-reference of capture group #1 followed by 1+ digits. Repeat this group 0 or more times


)?: End non-capture group 2. ? makes this group optional.


)?: End non-capture group 1. ? makes this group optional.
\]: Match closing ]


I don't think this matches a list with only one element. You need to make the first delimiter optional.

Yes I can do that but even OP is using \d*[,;]) so assumption was different.

It works for lists of one element, but not zero but thats completely fine! I don't actually need to match strings I listed in the problem, but an adjacent problem that relies on this solution, so thank you!

Just use \d* after [ to be able to match []

Not sure if they want to match a leading separator, but I came up with this https://regex101.com/r/4YVYqw/1

Very good catch and good enhancement @Thefourthbird. I have edited further to incorporate your suggestion.

Use alernative patterns with |.
\[\d+(?:(?:,\d+)*|(?:;\d+)*)\]

(?:,\d+)* matches a sequence of numbers each preceded by ,.
(?;\d+)* matches a sequence of numbers each preceded by ;.
DEMO
